# Простая функция для определения целого числа...

Tags: c++

Здравствуйте, не подскажете, как можно определить, что ввел пользователь (в смысле целое число или нет)? Допустим, ввел 67-целое, 8.7- не целое, 7f89-не целое. Спасибо!

Comment: Вообще, это уже [обсуждалось](http://hashcode.ru/questions/64425/).

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, там речь о проверки числа, а тут - строки.

Answer (score 4):

Ну насчёт простой -- не знаю, но вот:

```
 int f(const char *p) {
     if (!p) return 0;
     if (*p == '-' || *p == '+') p++;
     do {
         if (*p < '0' || *p > '9') return 0;
     } while (*++p);
     return 1;
 }
```

Comment: сложновато, но спасибо

Comment: Проще регекспами.

Comment: только еще бы хорошо сначала сделать над строкой что-то вроде trim, т.е. обрезать пробелы и разные там табуляции. Мало ли чего может напихать пользователь. А так пожалуй самый юзабельный ответ.

Comment: При вводе из потока пробелов быть не должно.

 Только если передать "456.00", то она вернёт что это не целое число.

Comment: Если получать строку при помощи метода getline, то вполне могут попасться пробелы

Answer (score 3):

```
double value;
cin >> value;
bool isInt=(value==floor(value));
```

либо:

```
bool isInt=(value==int(value));
```

isInt примет true, если число целое, иначе false. При этом целым будет считаться и число 42.0, в отличие от метода со строкой, в предыдущем ответе. При использовании первого варианта не забудь подключить math.h.

P. S. Предпросмотр ХэшКода не работает правильно. Выводит всё в одну строку и ничего не парсит.

Comment: "P. S. Предпросмотр ХэшКода не работает правильно. Выводит всё в одну строку и ничего не парсит"-ну насчет этого 100% согласен)))
Ну, только почему-то если ввожу не целое- заклинивает цикл:
int main()
{
while(1)
{
double value;
cin >> value;
bool isInt=(value==floor(value));
if(isInt) cout<<"Yes!";
else cout<<"no";
}
 return 0;
}

Comment: Только если вводится слово, смешанное из букв и цифр и начинающееся с цифр, то все равно будет распознаваться как целое число.

Answer (score 2):

Возможный вариант:

```
if (strlen(number) == strspn(number, "0123456789"))
    ; // TODO:
```

Comment: а если из потока?

Comment: А также и из потока. Просто читать словами в переменную. Например:

    string number;
    while (cin >> number)
    {
        ; // TODO:
    }

Comment: спасибо, пока GLmonster дал, как мне кажется, лучший вариант.

Answer (score 1):

http://codepad.org/R9IanZ7e

```
#include <cstdio>

bool check(const char *s)
  {
  int n=0;
  sscanf(s, "%*d%n", &n);
  return !s[n];
  }

#define TEST(x) puts(check(#x) ? #x " - yes" : #x " - no")

int main(void)
  {
  TEST(1);
  TEST(1.8);
  TEST(-890);
  TEST(+890);
  TEST(0x100);
  TEST(1e3);
  TEST(ghjghjghj);
  TEST(99999999999999999999);
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: Изящный способ.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<cmath> using namespace std;

int main() {
    float a1=7.7;
    float a2=71.711;
    float a3=77;
    float a1_a1=a1-=floor(a1);
    float a2_a2=a2-=floor(a2);
    float a3_a3=a3-=floor(a3);
    if (a1_a1==0) cout<<a1<<" - not full!"<<endl; else cout<<a1<<" - full!"<<endl;
    if (a2_a2==0) cout<<a2<<" - not full!"<<endl; else cout<<a2<<" - full!"<<endl;
    if (a3_a3==0) cout<<a3<<" - not full!"<<endl; else cout<<a3<<" - full!"<<endl;
    system("Pause");
    }
```

Comment: МММ, вообщем работает, но если ввести в cin>>a2=t6, то он говорит, что всё хорошо, хотя это не так...

Comment: на этот случай стоит проверять ввел ли пользователь вообще число.

Answer (score 0):

Анализ результатов вызова **strtol()** (подробности в man) поможет Вам.